# Order of methods from Object#methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

Does Ruby specify the order of methods returned from `Object#methods`? It seems to be done in order of definition in MRI, but I didn't see that specified in the documentation.

Comment: Why do you need to know? Just curiosity?

Comment: I was doing a kata and saw a way to cycle through available operations by using the list of available methods. So yeah, mostly academic curiosity.